# Button with multi line text is little bit shifted below in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I want to multi line text on a `button` but multi lining make it little bit shift down 
How to fix it?

[image: Buttons]

Here is XML code of `Button`:-

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_buttons"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
    <TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:background="#BAFFBA"
        android:text="@string/clock" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Alarm"
        android:text="@string/Alarm"
        android:background="#004819"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
            android:background="#BAFFBA"
            android:text="@string/Stopwatch" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:background="#BAFFBA"
            android:text="@string/Timer" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Here is `string` stopwatch:-

```
<string name="Stopwatch">Stop&#10;Watch</string>
```

Comment: can you past your full code xml

Comment: can u add match_parent for the height of buttons or does that ruin the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tab_buttons"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clock"
            android:background="#BAFFBA"
            android:text="CLOCK" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Alarm"
            android:text="ALARM"
            android:background="#004819"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
            android:background="#BAFFBA"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Stop&#10;Watch" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:background="#BAFFBA"
            android:text="TIMER" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Just apply `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to stopwatch Button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_buttons"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:background="#BAFFBA"
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/clock" />

    <Button
        android:background="#004819"
        android:id="@+id/Alarm"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/Alarm"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:background="#BAFFBA"
        android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/Stopwatch" />

    <Button
        android:background="#BAFFBA"
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="@string/Timer" />
</LinearLayout>
```